# Get pygame to play sound when sensor is triggered with tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Each sound is played when the sound function is called, but I cannot get it to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pygame.mixer.music can only loads a file a time.

you may want to create a sound object:

```
#Note only wav and ogg will be supported
snd_left = pygame.mixer.Sound('/media/pi/1278-1B75/Audio/left.wav')
```

then play by

```
snd_left.play()
```

also, you should load the sound file on startup and **only once**,

so do pygame.init() / pygame.mixer.init(),

although initializing multiple times won't cause error.

So the result will be like this

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
#Load sound files after mixer initalized.
sound()

def update_display():
    global sensors
    global snd_left #You may want to load more files here
    #Read the sensors
    sensors = sensorVals()
    if sensors:
        if detect_something():
            snd_left.play()

def sound():
    global snd_left #remember to use global
    snd_left = pygame.mixer.Sound('/media/pi/1278-1B75/Audio/left.wav')
```

Comment: According to the PyGame document, `pygame.mixer.Sound()` object supports OGG and WAV file only.